# Magento 2.2 with PHP 7.1.9 Issue

Tags: magento2, cli

I have a MultiPHP Manager on my WHM and I have installed Magento 2.2 with PHP 7.1.9. However, whenever I execute a simple cli command I receive an error Magento supports 7.0.2, 7.0.4 and 7.0.6 or later - see screenshot. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: run `php -v` and make sure the version is 7.1.9 on the same console.

Comment: that says PHP 5.6.31 which is what is installed on my server

Comment: So you got it. Your current PHP version is 5.6.x and M2.2 needs PHP 7.x. It's time to upgrade your PHP

Comment: With the MultiPHP manager I have set the website to run on PHP 7.1.9. If I look at www.mydomain/info.php it says I am on 7.1.9

Comment: Please see my edit in the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, still your PHP server is using 5.6.31 version. So you need to upgrade your PHP in order to use Magento 2.2

### EDIT

Your console is still relying on PHP version 5.6.x. It is true that using your MultiPHP manager you are running your site on version 7.x. But it means your apache PHP version is only changed. However, CLI is not relying on Apache configuration, which still relies on your default PHP setup. So you need to upgrade that too.

You can fix this in many ways. A **[good start](https://superuser.com/questions/971867/why-is-the-php-version-different-in-phpinfo-and-cli)** is here. Then look for the best way that will work for you.

Comment: The website is running fine and wouldn't even be up and running if I was using PHP 5.6 as its not compatible with M2.2

Comment: See my edit please

Comment: I can't upgrade the PHP version on my server as I still have Magento 1 websites. Is there another way to do this? I tried php7.1 bin/magento cache:clean but it doesn't recognize the command.

Comment: I am not sure. Try to change the php version for the current shell session. Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206864/use-different-php-version-cli-executable-for-one-command

Comment: btw in my computer, I have php 7.1.6 and I have m2 and m1 in my machine. Both runs without any problem. However, there is always exist the risk of external extension that you have used in your m1 instance(it may fail).

Comment: In the end, what was your solution?

Comment: You put me in the right direction. I used the path to my PHP 7.1 binary then bin/magento cache:clean and it worked

Answer (score 0):

If the above approaches do not work (they did not work for me), explicitly recite the php version on the command line:

```
/usr/local/php71/bin/php /home/your-magento-directory/bin/magento cache:clear
```

or

```
/usr/local/php71/bin/php /home/your-magento-directory/bin/magento other-magento-command
```

Answer (score 0):

Before running any php command on my vps with plesk panel I run:

```
export PATH=/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin:$PATH
```

or

```
export PATH=/opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin:$PATH
```

After that

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

or any php magento command

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple PHP version on your server then you need to specify the php version in command line because from multiple PHP version, one PHP version is set as Default so please run below command for PHP7.1:

/opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php bin/magento cache:flush;
/opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php bin/magento indxer:reindex;

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

use this command for executing this specific command in PHP 7.2

```
/etc/php/7.2     php  /home/tm/dockercontainer/magento2folder/bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```