# There are no commands defined in the "indexer" namespace. php 7.2 (ubuntu)

Tags: magento2, indexer

When i want to re Index in Magento2 in php version of 7.3,
this display me this error

An exception was raised while creating "Request"; no instance returned

And when i change to version 7.2
Display this Error.....
[image]

Also i use this command with my root Directory (same error)

So how can i simply use Indexer command in Magento2

I thing something too wrong with my Magento :(
Also check this image :--
[image]

My all commands are not working.
**Also i change my Magento Folder Permissions**

Comment: also when i run any command like bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

this Display Error Like:-
An exception was raised while creating "Request"; no instance returned

Comment: The error that the indexer namespace is missing can be related to a previous error when installing dependencies or setting the configurations. Maybe recheck previous commands you executed. Otherwise, check if you can set up a local magento system and check if you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: i add a new image when i write another commands display these errors...
please check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please mention your **Magento Version** first.

> An exception was raised while creating "Request"; no instance returned

Your First error is coming due to most likely not changing php version properly, you should only use **PHP version 7.2** when you're working on **Magento 2.3.x**

> Change PHP version according to your Magento version, refer below link
>   if you're using Magento 2.3.x

**https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html**

Try below commands for changing PHP version

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

Also refer this link for similar issue

**[Magento 2.2 with PHP 7.1.9 Issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195373/magento-2-2-with-php-7-1-9-issue?rq=1)**

> About your second error regarding 7.2 version,

Try to give permission first to your Magento Directory

```
sudo chmod -R 777 magentoDir
```

then use your upgrade-deploy commands.

if that doesn't help try to find solution in below link.

**https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/CLI-not-recognizing-magento-commands/td-p/45869**

Comment: Yes it is Version Error, also when i change my php version to 7.2 all commands are run normally.
But when start admin panel with php changed version 7.2 , My admin panel was to working.
so always i change my php version and apply all these commands and again change version to 7.3.

after that i found a short way to apply my commands without change version is:- /usr/bin/php7.2 bin/magento indexer:reindex

so if you have anny suggestion for this please give me 
Thanks

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Comment: now i write my full comment Please read it now

Comment: you can use `php7.2 bin/magento indexer:reindex` if this solved your problem mark it as accepted so it will help others.

Comment: Thanks This command Helps me alwayes
php7.2 bin/magento indexer:reindex